Pdf table pasted into excel via word but there is hidden text i dont want. I cannot find how to remove
My excel data appears to be cells like 200.00 BUT I cannot add up because the actual cell content is Money in (£) 200.00.  So it has text at start and . at end that I don't see in the display. I just want to copy the spreadsheet as it displays so I can work with the data but every cell has header info to left and . to right of the number and all of it gets picked up in a copy and paste. It was a bank statement pdf. I moved it to word then copied into excel as I don't have software to convert pdf to excel directly and saw the word method on youtube.

Why not use Power Query to transform data from PDF to Excel. ReadHere
